# Importing siunitx gives warning "file [...] does not appear to be a dictionary"

Tags: siunitx, warnings, translations

Why does the following minimal document result in the warning?

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[catalan]{babel}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
Prova.
\end{document}
```

**Warning:**

> Package translations Warning: file `translations-basic-dictionary-catalan.trsl' does not appear to be a dictionary on input line 6.

When I don't import the `siunitx` package, the warning disappears.

I'm using pdfTeX to compile the document, and am using TeX Live 2022.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: Thanks @barbarabeeton :) Glad to be here!

Comment: looks like a bug in the translations package. The catalan file declares a spanish dictionary. Actually there is already an issue https://github.com/cgnieder/translations/issues/22

Comment: Thank you so much @UlrikeFischer!! :) It seems like somebody created a PR to fix this as well, so hopefully it will be fixed soon: https://github.com/cgnieder/translations/pull/24.